# Need Jquery code to check the input type:checked in all TR inside table

Tags: jquery

I need to Check about the input type:checked in all tr inside table and after that i need to give event for that. Could you please help me on this??below is my code

```
$('.view-all-check').click(function (event) {
                        if (this.checked) {
                          $('.message tr input').each(function () {
                              this.checked = true;
                              $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');

                          });
                      } else {
                          $('.message tr input').each(function () {
                              this.checked = false;
                              $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');

                          });
                      }
                  });
"
```

Comment: You should probably show your table markup as well

Comment: you could use this: `$('.message input:checkbox:checked')`

Answer (score 1):

From your code i think you're trying to add/remove active class to `tr` and check/uncheck all checkboxes, Your code looks fine but you have to change it to this:

```
$('.view-all-check').click(function (event) {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.message tr input').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', true); // Check all checkboxes
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('active'); // Change here    
        });
    } else {
        $('.message tr input').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', false); // un-check all checkboxes
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('active'); // Change here
        });
    }
});
```

### [**Prorotype / Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dw8Kx/)

For reverse process, Give unique class name to each textboxes and get length of  the checked checkboxes with `:checked` and compare it with `checkbox` which are having class `.chk` so it will be `(.chk).length == (.chk:checked).length`

You can try this code

```
$(".chk").change(function(){
    if($(".chk").length == $(".chk:checked").length)
        $(".view-all-check").prop('checked', true);
    else
        $(".view-all-check").prop('checked', false);
});
```

### [**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dw8Kx/2/)

Comment: thanks for your answer Dhaval.actually i need to check the title checkbox:checked when i check all the check box which is nested to title checkbox

Comment: @user3583964 Code does the same! Did you see fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('.view-all-check').change(function (event) {
    if(this.checked){
        $('.message tr input[type="checkbox"]').closest('tr').addClass('active');
    }else{
        $('.message tr input[type="checkbox"]').closest('tr').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

---

Instead of `click` event you could use the `change` event on the `$('.view-all-check')` element.

---

As per your comment you can try this:

```
$('.message input[type="checkbox"]').change(function (event) {
    var isChecked = $('.message input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length === $('.message input[type="checkbox"]').length;
    if(isChecked){
        $('.view-all-check').prop('checked', isChecked);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Jai.actually i need to check the title checkbox:checked when i check all the check box which is nested to title checkbox

Comment: @user3583964 checkout the updated answer, there you have to check if `:checked` input length is equal to the length of the checkboxes length then check the target.

Comment: thanks a lot i got it from your code. really you are a expert in jquery.